# How to print the most common element of a list?

Tags: python, list, slice, libraries

I need help finding how to print the most common letter of a string as a character after using the `most_common` function is used. My code is:

```
from collections import*
message = input("What is the message you would like to decrypt?")
messageInt = list(map(ord,list(message)))
messageChr = list(map(chr,list(messageInt)))
print messageChr
fre = Counter(messageChr)
mostLett = fre.most_common(1)
print mostLett
```

How do I get it to print:

```
['e', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e']
[('e', 2)]
e
```

Comment: Are you using Python2 or Python3?

Comment: print isn't a function in his code, so I assume python2

Answer (score 2):

```
    l = ['e', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e']

    Counter(l).most_common(1)[0][0]
    or 
    Counter(l).most_common(1).pop()[0]
    or
    mostCommonLetter, _ = Counter(l).most_common(1).pop()
    mostCommonLetter
    'e'
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python 2, which is what I assume you're using,

```
from collections import*
message = raw_input("What is the message you would like to decrypt?")
messageInt = list(map(ord,list(message)))
messageChr = list(map(chr,list(messageInt)))
print messageChr
fre = Counter(messageChr)
mostLett = fre.most_common(1)
print mostLett
print mostLett[0][0]
```

replace `input()` with `raw_input()` and add the bottom line.